# How do I create 2 column divs that stack on top of each at different screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

The div container is breaking my page. It's overriding a container used elsewhere. Is there any other alternative I can use to still have the same effect i.e the div columns sit next to each but at different screen resolutions, they stack on top of each other, and both retain equal width and length as they shrink?

How do I create two responsive divs that sit next to each other and stack on top of each other at different screen sizes? The dimensions are specific (each div is 350 x 217 px).

One div will have a text centred horizontally within the div but also left aligned and the other will be an image.

Below is the ideal end result. I'm a newbie to dev and this is for an assignment that's overdue. I've been fiddling around for the past couple of days and I keep going round in circles.

[image]

Responsive view on smaller screens:

[image]

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background-color: #e0e620;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="center">The Info.<br />
      <a class="link-button-green" href="" title="Info 
        guide">Download now</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x217.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is 350 x 217. Here is the ideal look below:

The below screen is what I would like to achieve without changing the existing width and height of yellow div? How do I go about achieving that?

Comment: So, you want these divs to appear full width and stacked up until 800px? Beyond 800px, you want the side by side?

Comment: I've changed that 600px. Side by side until they hit the 600px mark then they get stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Are there going to be images in both of these divs? Or is one going to be an image and the other yellow? I'm asking because I am going to use actual images in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. No, the yellow div (left) will contain text and a call to action (text and cta should be middle of the div but left aligned). The right div will be the image but both are 350 x 217px.

Comment: Millhorn, keen to see your solution.

Comment: Mine is posted. I think this is a good example on providing solutions with `flexbox` vs `grid`. They're both useful in this case... just depends on what you prefer. I generally use flexbox for everything.

Comment: @Millhorn read the comments under my question. Initially, I used flexbox but your solution does not make both elements the same height on small devices.

Comment: you msotlikely have contradicting styles. Use different classes or ID's if you do not want other elements to be affected by the CSS

Comment: (CSS Grid Layout ||  flexbox) are great for responsive layout

Answer (score 1):

1. add `display: grid` to the parent element `.row`;
2. add `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` to the parent element (`.row`) to have a 2-column layout.
3. For screens at 600px or below you change the `grid-template-columns` to `1fr` for the element `.row` to get a 1-column layout. To have both elements have the same height, you can use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` on the parent element.
4. To maintain the normal block-level-behavior you add `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to the `.left` column. Flexbox will allow you do vertical center the text.
5. To vertical center the text you have to align it to the main-axis (`flex-direction: column`) with `justify-content: center`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    .row {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    }
}

.left {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
    <div class="center">The Info.<br />
      <a class="link-button-green" href="" title="Info 
        guide">Download now</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x217.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tacoshy. How come in the responsive view the image stays the same but the yellow div with text shrinks sizes? How can I shrink both equally at different screen sizes. Sorry mate, I'm a newbie so be patient with me.

Comment: That would require a completely different approach with CSS-Grid to let both columns have the same height. Also what you mean is not "responsive view" but on "small devices"

Comment: I see. Can you please assist with this? I want to send you the result I'm getting on my end.

Comment: already did, just changing the explanation

Comment: Thank you. How do I move text to the middle of the div but left aligned? Right now, it's next to the border.

Comment: add a padding ...

Comment: Will try your solution too @Tacoshy. Thanks mate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247574/discussion-between-ef-1000-and-tacoshy).

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs work.

You want the specific div widths to be 350px x 217px, but when you get to a min-width of 600px, that width of 350px isn't going to work anymore. You will struggle to have a responsive page if you set explicit heights and widths. You need to let elements fill their spaces naturally.

That said, I've created a solution that I think would work best based on the images you've provided.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 217px;
  }
}

.inner {
  background-color: #E0E61F;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 217px;
}
.inner span {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  min-height: unset;
}
.inner img {
  min-height: 217px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <span><a href="#">The Info</a></span>
    <span>Download Now</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/1600/900" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just not how to develop responsively. If you set explicit heights/widths, as you did, then as the screen grows, the image is going to get blurry. It's better in that case to use a single higher resolution image, and then the picture element and assign heights/widths based on the viewport.

Comment: Is there an alternative for using div container @Millhorn? This is because a container is overriding the existing container used elsewhere on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above i would start with mobile view. You can create a parent div around your two boxes called `container` with the following css properties

`display:flex`
`flex-direction: column`

Then add a media query set at the width you would like this divs to be side by side and change the flex direction on your container div to row

`flex-direction: row`

Comment: Thanks mate but the div container is breaking my page. Is there any other alternative I can use to still have the same effect i.e the div columns sit next to each but at different screen resolutions, they stack on top of each other and both retaining equal width and length as they shrink?